# Implementing specific template instances in source with inherited template parameters

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance, c++20

I have the following template class:

```
// A.hpp

class A_data {
public:
  int foo = 1;

  virtual ~A_data() = default;
};

template <class C = A_data> class A {
public:
  int foo() const; // Not implemented here

  A() { d = new C; }
  ~A() { delete d; }

  C* d;
};
```

I implement the default instance of `A`:

```
// A.cpp

#include "A.hpp"

// Template source implementation
template <> int A<A_data>::foo() const { return d->foo; }
```

Now, I can use the class with the default instance:

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>

#include "A.hpp"

int main() {
  A a;
  std::cout << a.foo(); // Prints 1
}
```

However, suppose I want to create a class which inherits `A`, along with its own data class which inherits `A_data`, like so:

```
// A.hpp

class B_data : public A_data {
public:
  int bar = 2;

  virtual ~B_data() = default;
};

// Template here is in case something needs to inherit B, like in A.
template <class C = B_data> class B : public A<C> {
public:
  int bar() const; // Not implemented here, just like A::foo.
};

// A.cpp

template <> int B<B_data>::bar() const { return d->bar; }
```

This results in the following problem:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "A.hpp"

int main() {
  B b;
  std::cout << b.bar(); // Works fine, prints 2
  std::cout << b.foo(); // Linker error: no implementation of A<B_data>::foo!
}
```

As you can probably glean from the example, the intent is to have a class with its own data container (in this case `A` and `A_data`), such that other classes can inherit it (`B`), and can optionally choose to expand the data container by inherting the parent's container (`B_data`).

I can get around this problem by defining the implementation in `A.hpp`, but in this case I don't want to provide multiple interfaces of `A` other than `A_data` and its derived classes. If I really wanted to, I could implement each instance in `A.cpp`, but it adds nothing of value since the implementation itself is invariant.

My expectation was that `B<B_data>` would be able to "know" about `A<A_data>` and use `A <A_data>::foo`, since `B` inherits from `A`. Obvously, since `B<B_data>` and `B<A_data>` are not related, this is not the case -- but can it be?

Can I achieve this "expanding class" interface without exposing the implementation in the header? If not, is there a better alternative that would still allow me to maintain this simple interface?

Part of the reason templates seemed to be appealing here as opposed to regular class inheritence is because they allow to automatically dereference the correct container data without doing any type of pointer casts. Example with regular classes:

```
#include "A.hpp"

int A::foo() const { return d->foo; }
int B::bar() const { return d->bar; } // Compiler error: No member 'bar' in 'A_data'
```

Comment: @JeJo The linker. It ignores it entirely and only sees the header declaration. This was something I've tried before, and from my understanding it can't be done as it results in `undefined reference to 'A<B_data>::foo() const'`

Comment: @JeJo It works if the template implementation is in `main.cpp` instead of its own file, but fails linking if I compile with `g++ --std=c++20 main.cpp A.cpp -o test`.

Comment: In the non-templated case, if you can guarantee that `d` points to `B_data` (e.g. because that's what you did in `B`'s constructor and nowhere else you reassign this pointer), then there's no problem doing `static_cast<B_data*>(d)`, this conversion will, unlike `dynamic_cast`, result in no runtime overhead/checks.

Comment: @daedsidog Templated entities, including member functions of class templates should be implemented in the header, not in the source file. So move the definition to `A.hpp`. Honestly, I haven't understood what your intention here is really either, though.

Comment: *"I can get around this problem by defining the implementation in A.hpp"*  It seems it is the way to go...  *"but in this case I don't want to provide multiple interfaces of A"* I don't understand what you mean `int foo() const { return d->foo; }` would be fine.

Comment: BTW, `A` doesn't respect [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), `std::unique_ptr<C>` is a way to fix the issue.

Comment: @Jarod42 My bad, I meant specializations instead of interfaces. I since then realized perhaps I am misusing templates here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to templates, you can implement this 'mirrored inheritance' as follows: make `B<B_data>` inherit from `A<A_data>` instead of `A<B_data>` by declaring in `B_data` (or other possible template argument types) an alias `base` to a whatever type you want to consider base for your purposes (it's ambiguous in general, since there may be many bases of a class) and making `B<C>` inherit from `A<C::base>`. Then, for `B<C>`, since `d` is of type `C::base*`, it can still hold a pointer to `C` which is derived from `C::base` (assuming `C::base` is set adequately and is an actual base). But in this case, we need to provide a custom default constructor in `B` so that it constructs `C` object for `d`, not `C::base` which would happen if default constructor for `A<C::base>` would be called by implicitly defaulted default constructor of `B<C>` (note that there's no need to provide destructor since `delete d` from `A<C::base>`'s destructor will work correctly if `C::base` has virtual destructor). Then, since inside `B<C>` we know how we constructed the object `d` points to, we can safely assume we know its dynamic type and access it through `static_cast`-ed pointer (for safety you could e.g. add `dynamic_cast`-check inside `assert` for Debug-builds check).

Example implementation (see also comments, in particular for some changes of other aspects of your code):

```
// A.hpp

class A_data {
public:
    int foo = 1;

    virtual ~A_data() = default;
};

template <class C = A_data> class A {
public:
    int foo() const;

    A() { d = new C; }
    // 'virtual' is not strictly needed in our particular case since we don't delete B
    // through A*, but still it is safer and best practice with it than without
    virtual ~A() { delete d; }

    C* d;
};

class B_data : public A_data {
public:
    using base = A_data;
    int bar = 2;

    // virtual ~B_data() = default; implicitly defaulted and virtual
};

template <class C = B_data> class B : public A<typename C::base> {
public:
    B() { this->d = new C; } // 'this' needed to trigger dependent name lookup
    int bar() const;
};

// A.cpp

#include "A.hpp"

template <> int A<A_data>::foo() const { return d->foo; }
template <> int B<B_data>::bar() const { return static_cast<B_data*>(d)->bar; }

// main.cpp

#include <iostream>

#include "A.hpp"

int main() {
    B b;
    std::cout << b.bar();
    std::cout << b.foo();
}
```

Note also that if you want to use different template arguments `C`, you may want to avoid code duplication in specialization definitions in *A.cpp*. There, you can define your templated functions usually (not as specializations), but to force instantiations use *explicit template instantiations*. E.g. suppose there's `B_data_2` class defined like this:

```
// in A.hpp
class B_data_2 : public A_data {
public:
    using base = A_data;
    int bar = 3;
};
```

It also has `bar` public data member, but with different default initializer. Now we can add another specialization for `B<B_data_2>::bar()` to *A.cpp*, but it will be basically the same as `B<B_data>::bar()`, so code duplication arises:

```
// in A.cpp
template <> int A<A_data>::foo() const { return d->foo; }
template <> int B<B_data>::bar() const { return static_cast<B_data*>(d)->bar; }
template <> int B<B_data_2>::bar() const { return static_cast<B_data_2*>(d)->bar; }
```

Instead, if we replace specializations with general definitions followed by explicit instantiation definitions of methods, we have:

```
// in A.cpp
template<class C> int A<C>::foo() const { return d->foo; }
template int A<A_data>::foo() const;

template<class C> int B<C>::bar() const {
    return static_cast<C*>(this->d)->bar; // Again 'this' to enable dependent name lookup
}
template int B<B_data>::bar() const;
template int B<B_data_2>::bar() const;
```

This obviously scales better, but to avoid doing explicit instantiation for every member function of the same specialization, we can do even better -  explicitly instantiate whole class specializations, which will, in particular, automatically instantiate all (non-templated) member functions of that specializations:

```
// in A.cpp
template<class C> int A<C>::foo() const { return d->foo; }

template<class C> int B<C>::bar() const {
    return static_cast<C*>(this->d)->bar; // Yet again 'this' to enable dependent name lookup
}

template class A<A_data>;
template class B<B_data>;
template class B<B_data_2>;
```

Now we can test and see that it compiles and works:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "A.hpp"

int main() {
    B b;
    B<B_data_2> b_2;
    std::cout << b.bar() << b.foo() << std::endl; // 21
    std::cout << b_2.bar() << b_2.foo() << std::endl; // 31
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you for the in-depth explaination.

Answer (score 0):

Putting implementation in header would be fine in your case, and you don't need specialization:

```
class A_data {
public:
  int foo = 1;

  virtual ~A_data() = default;
};

template <class C = A_data>
requires(requires(C c) { c.foo; } ) // Possibly, in C++20
class A
{
public:
  int foo() const { return d->foo; }

  A() = default;

  std::unique_ptr<C> d = std::make_unique<C>();
};

class B_data : public A_data {
public:
  int bar = 2;

  virtual ~B_data() = default;
};

// Template here is in case something needs to inherit B, like in A.
template <class C = B_data>
requires(requires(C c) { c.foo; c.bar;} ) // Possibly, in C++20
class B : public A<C> {
public:
  int bar() const { return this->d->bar; }
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
  B b;
  std::cout << b.bar();
  std::cout << b.foo();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Mj7Y445co)

Answer (score -4):

The **problem** is that you've explicitly specialized `foo` for the template argument `A_data` instead of `B_data`.

To **solve** this just change the explicit specialization to be for the argument `B_data` as shown below:

**A.cpp**

```
#include "A.hpp"

//----------------vvvvvv---------------------------------->changed from A_data to B_data
template <> int A<B_data>::foo() const { return d->foo; }
template <> int B<B_data>::bar() const { return d->bar; }
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "A.hpp"

int main() {
  B b;
  std::cout << b.bar(); // Works fine, prints 2
  std::cout << b.foo(); // WORKS FINE, prints 1
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/NCaCYzoiXs)

The output of the above modified program is:

```
21
```

##### Explanation

`B` is instantiated with `B_data` and so it inherits from `A<B_data>`. Note carefully that it inherits from `A<B_data>` and not `A<A_data>`. This means that `foo`'s implementation for `A<B_data>` should be provided. But you never provided `foo`'s implementation for `A<B_data>` because what you actually provided was implementation of `foo` for `A<A_data>` and hence the error. Thus by changing `A_data` to `B_data` as shown in the modified code above, we get rid of the error.

Comment: While it solves this case, [it shifts the problem over to `A`](https://onlinegdb.com/XrO0pXwaj).

Comment: @daedsidog Note that your given link works fine as it should since it is the same as mine.Moreover, note the explanation that i have added at the end of my answer.In particular, `B` is instantiated with `B_data` and so it inherits from `A<B_data>`.Note carefully that it inherits from `A<B_data>` and not `A<A_data>`.This means that `foo`'s implementation for `A<B_data>` should be provided. But you never provided `foo`'s implementation for `A<B_data>` because what you actually provided was implementation of `foo` for `A<A_data>` and hence the error. The same is explained at the end of my answer.

Comment: It's all clear to me, but it would mean I would have to provide an implementation for every possible specialization, which as I mentioned in my question -- is somethiing I want to avoid.